# How do I use FAISS searching with Haystack?

Tags: machine-learning, data, search-engine

I have a private SQL database with text entries in it. I want to create a search engine to query these entries. I have been looking into haystack (https://haystack.deepset.ai/overview/intro) with the FAISS document store (https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/main/haystack/document_stores/faiss.py).

The documentation is atrocious and I could use some help. I've been looking for hours and the answers simply aren't there.

**How do I connect the FAISSDocumentStore with my private SQL database?**

The following questions are unclear to me (and any sane person who reads their terrible documentation)

What is the definition of a document store (not even present on their website)? How does it relate to my private SQL database? Is it the same? Is it part of it? Is it saved to disc and if so how does this make any sense? When I add entries in my private SQL database, how do I reindex the FAISS indexes? How do I tell FAISS to index only the 'text' column in my private SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DocumentStore

As you can read [in the docs](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/document_store), you can think of the DocumentStore as a database that stores your texts and meta data and provides them to the Retriever at query time.

### FAISSDocumentStore

[`FAISSDocumentStore`](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/document-store-api#faissdocumentstore) is internally composed of:

- a SQL database to store texts and metadata
- a FAISS index to store vectors

I think this internal structure of `FAISSDocumentStore` is an implementation detail and you probably shouldn't care much about it...

### Integration with your data

You can't directly use your private SQL database in the `FAISSDocumentStore`.

Instead, I would consider the following steps (similar to [this tutorial](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/06_better_retrieval_via_embedding_retrieval)):

- initialize a new `FAISSDocumentStore`
- loop over your source database and write texts in`FAISSDocumentStore`, calling `document_store.write_documents` method
- initialize a retriever, such as `EmbeddingRetriever` (also consisting of an encoder to represent documents as vectors)
- compute and store vectors for your texts, by calling `document_store.update_embeddings(retriever)`
- save your `FAISSDocumentStore`
- repeat whenever your data changes...

### For more help...

- [Haystack Github discussions](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions)
- [Haystack Discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/qZxjM4bAHU)